# Sticky nav not smooth when bg added

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been trying to do a sticky navigation that first has a absolute position at bottom, but when the user scrolls `100vh` the sticky nav sticks at the top as a fixed position.

Now I've got it work somewhat fine, BUT when I add a image background to my sections, the navigation kind of "pops" to the top, instead of being a smooth transition. This only happens when I add a background IMAGE to the sections.

With image background: [www.avawi.com](http://www.avawi.com)
without image background: [www.avawi.com/test1](http://www.avawi.com/test1)

Been trying to solve this the entire night without success.

Comment: show us the problem. link please

Comment: It seems to be working well for me on both links. The "pop" problem you're running into may have to do with the image file being really huge (8.1 mb.) Try saving the file for web or optimizing it so the file size is much smaller

Comment: There are links in the post, but here you go: http://www.avawi.com and http://www.avawi.com/test1

Comment: @MattO'Connell will try to do so. However, this problem occurs on my desktop also. Shouldn't it work fine on desktop if the problem was the size of the image?